# How to make PyCharm display global variables in Python Console that are actually used by script?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, global-variables, watch

I run my script with Python Console in PyCharm and expect it to show global variables that are being used by script itself. But somehow it seems like it uses some different set to work with / different scope / namespace.

Here is a sample script:

```
def addb():
    global b
    b=1

def checkb():
    print('b' in globals())
```

I go to 'Run > Edit Configurations... > myscript' and check 'Run with Python console' there, press Run - Python Console opens - check Show Variables button and list of some global variables appears on the right. Then I write in prompt and get this response:

```
>>>'b' in globals()
False
>>>checkb()
False
```

Everything fine, no 'b' variable in variables list on right pane as well. Then I write and get this response:

```
>>>addb()
>>>checkb()
True
>>>'b' in globals()
False
```

Also, still no 'b' variable in variables list on the right pane. And this goes further, of course. This variable seems to be clearly existing and have appropriate value for functions and methods inside module, but not for Python Console. This is the most obvious example of such behavior. It goes further and bring undesirable consequences when I use some functions to change global variables state and use them in console. The variables changes their value "inside" of script, but remain the same state in console, etc.

What am I expecting to have is all actual script global variables' state be visible in variables list on the right pane of Python Console and be accessible from console so

```
>>>addb()
>>>'b' in globals()
```

would yield

```
True
```

I checked this in Python own console directly with

```
python -i test.py
```

and had exactly what I expected to have like I described above. So it's exactly PyCharm Python Console issue.

It looks completely like a bug behavior, but I just can't believe it is since it is too big and obvious not to notice so I just believe I missed something and decided to ask here first. Can't find anything relating this case in Google as well so I just stuck here. Would appreciate any guide or confirmation of it's buggy nature so I can raise an issue. Please let me know if you can't reproduce this issue as well.

I use PyCharm 2018.3.4 (Community Edition) Build #PC-183.5429.31, built on January 29, 2019 and Python 3.7.2.

Comment: I don't know how you're running this thing in PyCharm, but it looks like you're inspecting a different global namespace from the one `addb` and `checkb` are defined in. "Global" variables are module-level in Python; every module has its own globals.

Comment: @user2357112 yes, but somehow PyCharm inherits it at start and if I call `addb` in script, I'll see the changes at the right pane when console start. I want to know how to tune it correctly to remain in the same namespace during work.

Comment: So it is simply a bug in PyCharm. It is unfortunately still there. Maybe try to get someones attention at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-30940.